# Show text from MySql into input type text

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to show the query result in the input type="text"but for some reason the text is blank. I only have one result row so maybe I don't need the while statement. But yet I can't make it to show in the input type text. Can you help me a see if this method is okay our not? Thanks in advance

```
<label for="nomegrupo"><b>Editar nome do grupo 1 :</label</b><br>

                    <?php 

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result6)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['titulogrupo']; ?>" name="grupo1" id="velhas"></td>
                </tr> 
                <?php } ?>


                    <input type="submit" name="submit_x" data-inline="true" value="Submeter">
                  </form>
```

Comment: You'll need to properly HTML escape those values or it will trash your HTML if that value contains things like `"`.

Comment: Use `var_dump($row);` too see if u getting any data from query

Comment: Your code is correct.

Comment: So why doesn't appear? :/ the query is good, I used it several times

Comment: add `error_reporting(1); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` on top of your script to see real error

Answer (score -2):

If you are certain you are only getting 1 result you can try this:

```
<label for="nomegrupo"><b>Editar nome do grupo 1 :</label</b><br>

                <?php 

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result6)
if $row['titulogrupo']!='' {  ?>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['titulogrupo']; ?>" name="grupo1" id="velhas"></td>
            </tr> 
             <?php }  ?>


                <input type="submit" name="submit_x" data-inline="true" value="Submeter">
              </form>
```

Comment: do...while executes at least once, this means even if `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result6)` is `NULL`. So it may throw error *Undefined index `titulogrupo`* when there are no results to display.

Comment: Quite right. I have updated the answer to not use a while statement at all.